# How to stop on_message() in discord.py by using another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to stop a function using another function.

```
def on_message(message):
    #DO WHAT I WANT
    terminate_function(#if condition met)
def terminate_function():
    #terminate_function code
```

What should I put for #terminate_function code ?

Answer (score 1):

To exit out of a function you can use the `return` keyword.

```py
def on_message(message):
    # do what you want

    if "condition met":
        return

    print("this is not printed if the condition is met")
```

Comment: I know about this method, but I want to put the terminate function to break the def on_message(). Helpful though

Comment: That's one of the uses of the `return` keyword, as soon as it is met, the function ends.

Comment: I want the terminate_function to stop on_message.

Comment: *Why?* There's no reason for you to use another function and you cannot really do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a function return from another function. What you *could* do to solve this is make the `terminate` function return a `bool` & check that.

```py
def on_message(message):
    #DO WHAT I WANT
    if should_terminate():
        return

def should_terminate() -> bool:
    #DO SOMETHING
    return condition_met  # True if on_message should terminate, False if not
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want the other function to break the first one, an ugly solution is to throw an error.

```py
def on_message(message):
    #DO WHAT I WANT
    terminate_function()

def terminate_function():
    # Raising an exception here will make on_message stop as well
    raise RuntimeError()
```